# How to show/create dynamically shortest path based on traffic using android Google map Api v2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, shortest-path

Is there any feature in Android's Google Map API v2 to dynamically build a shortest path based on traffic along the journey, if not, are there any suggestions on how can I implement this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) to build a route with traffic times in mind. You can then convert the route into a polyline and put it onto your MapView, if you wish to display it.